# C++ operator Overloading the is equal operator

Tags: c++, object, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to learn operator overloading in C++.

I have followed a tutorial and overloaded the '==' operator to be able to compare objects of a class between them. Like this:

```
bool Vector2::operator==(const Vector2& v) const
{
    return ( (x_==v.GetX()) && (y_==v.GetY()) );
}
```

My class has two vars in it (`x_` and `y_`). I have created two objects from this class gave some values and compared them and it worked just fine. 
But then I used the `==` operator to compare to integers and it also worked fine. Now I was expecting the `==` operator to not work on integers because I had just overloaded it to do something else. But still it did. So I'm a little confused right now. And I have this question:

How comes the `==` operator after beiing overloaded like this can still be used to compare integers/floats/doubles/etc? In my case when it sees a Vector2 class object as the second parameter it acts like in the overloaded version and when it sees something else it acts normal?

Also another question: I have a `class classA` and a `class classB` both with 2 variables in them and only different in name. I create two objects one for `classA objA` and one for `classB objB` and I give some values with say a default constructor.

Now is it possible to overload the `operator ==` to do a comparasion like `if(objA==objB)`? Or do the operands in the expression need to be of the same type? Either `classA` or `classB`?

Please help me clear this up. Thank you for reading!

Comment: of what type is `x_` and `y_`?

Comment: You should add more source information.

Comment: You defined `==` for `Vector2`, not for `int`. Overloading is _by definition_ an implementation for _different_ types/arguments. Other implementations are unaffected. However if you were to ***redefine*** `==` for `int` that would be a different story.

Comment: Maybe your constructor is not `explicit` and the integers got implicitly converted to `Vector2`?

Comment: _when it sees something else it acts normal_ it is not normal (somehow compiler generated) when a class is comparable to an int.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: PS: It's really not clear what exactly you're asking. The benefit of ***code*** is that it's ***deterministic***. It's compiled exactly the same way that code would be compiled _every time_. On the other hand, your descriptions of what you overloaded and did and what happened (or thought happened) are all _open to interpretation_. Clearly you wrote some code. ***So show the code!*** and you'll get a much better answer. ;)

Comment: Operator overloading works like all other overloading. (Overloaded operators are exactly like regular functions, but with funky names.) All your questions can be answered if you study "normal" overloading and the potential surprises of having a converting constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Vector2` class has a constructor that takes an `int` and that is not marked `explicit`, it allows integers to be implicitly converted to `Vector2` as shown in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

struct S
{
    S(int x) : x(x) {}

    bool operator==(const S& other) const
    {
        return x == other.x;
    }
    int x;
};

int main() {
    S s1{5};
    S s2{5};

    assert(s1 == s2);

    assert(!(s1 == 5));

    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/ndKGvP)

This code compiles, but the second assertion fails, because 5 is converted into an `S`.